# Xfce application finder one Enter keystroke

Tags: xfce, xfce4

How to make application finder in Xfce 4 to launch an application with one Enter stroke when one choice is left?

Answer (score 0):

You can't (except for supplying a patch. http://bugzilla.xfce.org)

You can may try the xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Application Finder in Xfce can do as follows.

- In uncollapsed view: Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> *once* to launch the first matching command by autocomplete (Xfce 4.10 and newer)
- In collapsed view: Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> *twice* to launch the only choice left in list

[image: Application Finder with uncollapsed and collapsed view]

Then again, if user wanted to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once to launch the only choice left in list, that seems not possible.